# Isotropy groups of A4 and Fix(G)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=A_4$ act on itself by conjugation.

Find $Fix(G) = \{x \in G : gxg^{-1}=x \text{ for all }g \in G\}$

So, I think it is same as finding center of $G$, which is trivial.

Is this right?

Also, Find Isotropy group $G$ with $(12)(34) = \{g \in G : g(12)(34)g^{-1}=(12)(34)\}$

I first listed all elements of $A_4$ and tried to see which element does satisfy above condition, but this way seems really tedious and time-consuming.

Is there any way that I can find elements of Isotropy group without writing down all elements of $A_4$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct: The set of elements that are fixed, under the conjugation action of a group on itself, is indeed the center.

For the second part: Have you learned that conjugation is essentially a "change of basis" operation for permutation groups?

That is, given $g \in G$,

$$g(12)(34)g^{-1} = \big(g(1)g(2)\big)\big(g(3)g(4)\big).$$

This should make finding the stabilizer much easier. So, for example, $g = (13)(34)$ would work, etc. Any permutation that maps the set $\{1, 2\}$ to either $\{1, 2\}$ or $\{3, 4\}$ will work.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. It seems like I still have to know elements of A4, though.

Comment: Yes, of course you do. How could you come up with a list of elements  of $A_4$ (the stabilizer of that permutation) without knowing what's in $A_4$? That idea tells you exactly which handful of elements in $S_4$ you need to look at; you automatically know they fix the permutation, you just need to decide which of them are even. Alternatively, given the elements of $A_4$, it becomes trivial to decide if they fix the given permutation. Your comment, taken at face value, implies you were hoping for a method that required no knowledge of $A_4$ to calculate the centralizer of something in $A_4$.